# Chrome Extension for Bookmarking

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome Bookmarks API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928597/google-chrome-bookmarks-api)

Is it possible with the use of Chrome's Bookmarks API to load the bookmarks (stored locally) of an extension user in the bookmarks bar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I understand what you're asking the Chrome extension API allows you to interact with bookmarks. [Here are the docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html). Additionally here is some example code I've written that interacts with that API - I don't know what you're looking to do with bookmarks, but this attaches event listeners to the bookmark add and delete events and, on startup, will traverse their entire bookmark tree. [Code](https://github.com/thecoffman/indexmarks/blob/master/ext/background.html)

With some additional details about what you'd like to do - someone could probably provide a more thorough answer.

Comment: oh... sorry about that... I'm developing a Chrome Extension that caters user-specific bookmarks and browser preferences.. user data is stored in a file locally.. currently i can now write files using the NPAPI plugin.. my concern now is how do i let my extension a.) write the bookmarks in the user's file instead of the default user b.) load his/her personal bookmarks to the bookmarks bar -- using Chrome's bookmarks API.. I tried their sample code in their documentation but it doesn't work for me.. can someone shed a light on this?? thanks :D thanks for the answer too mr. thecoffman.